# basePacakage for many project in @RestControllerAdvice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-rest

i have parent project with multiple child project . 
all projects start with basepakage org.dordas.{project name}.web.controller . 
i want config all project in controllerAdvice with one basepackage but (star) not working .

```
@RestControllerAdvice(basePackages = { "org.baharan.**.web.rest" })
```

Comment: `basePackages` doesn't accept a regexp/ant style expression. It is only used the check if a package starts with that name. So indeed a star will not work. You will have to define each base package.

Comment: @M.Deinum i cant . i have parent project with multiple child project . i want config controllerAdvice in parent proejct without change in child projects.

Answer (score 1):

let say:

```
project
   |___ lib (module)
   |___ api (module)
```

You want to share `RestControllerAdvice` from `lib module` to `api module`

`lib module` has

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler
    public Type handler(Exception e){.....}

}
```

In `api module` add this below configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ExceptionAdvice.class})
public class FileServiceApplication {... }
```

Comment: This solution is not working unfortunately.