# RestControllerAdvice did not show custom exception in postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I created a custom exception hanle in a separate module and wanted to use the same GlobalExceptionHandle class in another module. Although an exception appears on the console, but no custom exception appears on the postman. What could be the reason for this? pls help me

**GlobalExceptionHandle.java**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class GlobalExceptionHandle extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<CustomExceptionResponseDto> handle(NotFoundException exception) {
        return new ResponseEntity<CustomExceptionResponseDto>(
                CustomExceptionResponseDto.builder()
                        .errorCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                        .message(exception.getMessage())
                        .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value())
                        .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                        .build(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        );
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidStateException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<CustomExceptionResponseDto> handle(InvalidStateException exception) {
        return new ResponseEntity<CustomExceptionResponseDto>(
                CustomExceptionResponseDto.builder()
                        .errorCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .message(exception.getMessage())
                        .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value())
                        .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                        .build(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
        );
    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<UserResponseDto> save(@RequestBody UserRequestDto userRequestDto) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.save(userRequestDto));
    }
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserResponseDto save(UserRequestDto userRequestDto) {
        log.info("User request dto: " + userRequestDto);

        userRepository.findUserByEmail(userRequestDto.getEmail()).ifPresent((user) -> {
            throw new EmailAlreadyUseException(user.getEmail());
        });

        var user = userMapper.userRequestDtoToUser(userRequestDto);
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(userRequestDto.getPassword()));
        return userMapper.userToUserResponseDto(userRepository.save(user));
    }

}
```

**InvalidStateException.java**

```
public class InvalidStateException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public InvalidStateException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

**EmailAlreadyUseException.java**

```
public class EmailAlreadyUseException extends InvalidStateException {
    public EmailAlreadyUseException(String email) {
        super(email+" already registered,try different email");
    }
}
```

[image][image][image]

Comment: Perhaps it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930985/basepacakage-for-many-project-in-restcontrolleradvice

Answer (score 0):

I see you're throwing `throw new EmailAlreadyUseException(user.getEmail());` but  you handle `@ExceptionHandler(InvalidStateException.class)` try to change into`@ExceptionHandler(EmailAlreadyUseException.class)` and check it out.